# How to insert Salesforce Activity History contents into custom field of a Contact?

Tags: salesforce

I am using Gmail, Salesforce integration app, using which I can save an interested mail into Salesforce Activity History of a Contact. Now, as soon as I receive the activity history, I want to save this into a custom field, named EmailBody__c.

Can any provide me a solution to it? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I have tried with the below trigger but have no luck.

```
trigger EmailBodyTrigger on Contact(before update) {
    Contact[] contacts = Trigger.new;
    for(Contact c : contacts) {
        try {
            ActivityHistory ah = c.ActivityHistories;
            if(ah != null) {
                contact.EmailBody__c = 'Hello Ram, How are you';
            }
        } catch(System.QueryException e) {
          // no trigger call   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to write trigger on activity history or activity object. So when activity is created related fields is need to update.

Comment: I did it already, but the trigger didn't get fired.